# How to automatically create ERD diagrams from pyspark tables?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, erd

Im having a ETL pipeline written in pyspark. I can autogenerate a DAG for this pipeline. However a DAG does not state anything about primary keys and entity relations (one-to-one, one-to-many etc.). Is it possible to automatically create ERD diagrams from pyspark dataframes? Do helper libraries exist for this?

Answer (score 0):

On Databricks they recommend using DBeaver to generate ERD's

Not sure if this can generalize to all pyspark.

https://www.databricks.com/blog/2020/02/21/working-with-entity-diagrams-on-databricks.html